# How do I convert NSDictionary to NSData as a plist (without saving the dictionary)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata

Does anyone know how to convert a NSDictionary object into an NSData object as a plist without saving the dictionary first?
I would like my iphone app to send an email with a plist containing my dictionary attached. I am currently using skpsmtpmessage, http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/, to send email.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `NSPropertyListSerialization` class for that. Have a look at its method:

```
+ (NSData *)dataFromPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format
                              errorDescription:(NSString **)errorString
```

> Returns an NSData object containing a
>   given property list in a specified
>   format.

Comment: This method is now deprecated in favor of dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:

Answer (score 6):

Use the [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. The Dev Centre tutorial on Archives has a section on [Serializing Objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/serializing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000952) which covers this.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 4.0, you should now be using the newer method below:

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format options:(NSPropertyListWriteOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```